# Color schemes on page load with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to load random pre-defined color schemes on page load with jQuery?

For example, I want to have color schemes *(for my 'h1', 'header background' and 'p')* saved, but on page load, it will randomly choose a color scheme.

I've tried searching around, and I couldn't find a way to do it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$(function() {

var colors = ['#111','#333','#555'],
background = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

$('header').css('background-color', background)

});
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? The code you have looks fine (however the colors are very similar).

Comment: [Your code works.](https://jsfiddle.net/vc792n5d/) What's the problem?

Comment: The code I have works, but I don't think it'll accomplish what I'm wanting.I don't want to generate random colors. I want to have a few sets of color schemes, and then load the color schemes on page load..

Comment: So you put the colors you want within the colors array.

Comment: Will it work though? For example, one of my color schemes would be a blue h1, black background, white p text. The second color scheme would be a yellow h1, grey background, purple p text. I want to load each set on random. I may be overthinking it.

Answer (score -3):

At least make colors.length into (colors.length-1). (Arrays start at index zero)

Comment: [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) produces values in the [0, 1) range, meaning it will give you a value from 0 to not-quite 1. The code they have is valid.

Comment: and this is not an answer, should be a comment